# Permission command is not working

Tags: permissions

I am working on Linux Mint. I am not so expert in permission commands. My directory is `/var/www/html/themeexplorer/destiniy/`. After  running `sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` command I found permission is not affected using `ll` command.

Why is it happening ?

[image]

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: It worked. Also check out `man chmod` Note the `-R` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were expecting but `chmod 755` on directories will give you `drwxr-xr-x`